# Driving without physical copy of License

Tags: driving, virginia

If you have a license and drive but forget your license and get pulled over what happens? Do you get a penalty for forgetting it at your house?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`If you have a license and drive but forget your license and get pulled over what happens?`

You could receive a summons or citation (a.k.a. "ticket") for failing to carry a driver's license. [Section § 46.2-104 of the Virginia Code](http://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title46.2/chapter1/section46.2-104/) states that it is a traffic infraction with a $10 fine to not have your license while driving.

> The operator of any motor vehicle, trailer, or semitrailer being
>   operated on the highways in the Commonwealth, shall have in his
>   possession: (i) the registration card issued by the Department or the
>   registration card issued by the state or country in which the motor
>   vehicle, trailer, or semitrailer is registered, and (ii) **his driver's
>   license**, learner's permit, or temporary driver's permit.
>
> Every person licensed by the Department as a driver . . .  who fails to carry his license. . .  for the vehicle which he
>   operates, shall be guilty of a traffic infraction and upon conviction
>   punished by a fine of ten dollars.

(Emphasis added.)

`Do you get a penalty for forgetting it at your house?`

Yes, if you have a valid license that you left at home, you can get the case dismissed by showing the license to the the court (presumably a clerk), but you will still have to pay "court costs."

> However, if any person summoned to appear before a court for failure
>   to display his license . . .  presents, before
>   the return date of the summons, to the court a license or permit
>   issued to him prior to the time the summons was issued . . . or appears pursuant to the
>   summons and produces before the court a license or permit issued to
>   him prior to the time the summons was issued . . . , he shall, upon payment of all applicable court
>   costs, have complied with the provisions of this section.

[Va. Code Ann. § 46.2-104 (2016).](http://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title46.2/chapter1/section46.2-104/)